# How do I pipeline an if?

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to decode a websocket response. If it contains the key 'symbol', I'd like to print it out.

I've done this:

```
msg                                                                                                                                   
|>Poison.decode!                                                                                                                      
|>Enum.member?("symbol")                                                                                                              
|>if                                             
|>IO.inspect
```

Unsurprisingly, it didn't like my 'if'. Is there a pipeline way of achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly you can't do it, because `You can't pipeline into macros!`
To achieve what you need just put this `if` into the proper function. Or even better - you do the conditional branching using different heads of the functions thanks to the pattern matching!

`Enum.member/2` will return true or false, so all you need is:

```
defp processing_the_response(true) do
  # something
end

defp processing_the_response(false) do
  # something ELSE
end
```

Answer (score 3):

[`Kernel.if/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#if/2) is defined with an arity of 2. In your pipe you call it with an arity of 1. This means there is no match for `Kernel.if/1`.

Also your `if` should return something for `IO.inspect` to inspect

```erl
[true, false] 
|> Enum.random() 
|> if(do: 42, else: "You can't handle the truth") 
|> IO.inspect
```

or maybe

```erl
[true, false]
|> Enum.random()
|> if do
        42
      else
        "You can't handle the truth"
      end
|> IO.inspect
```

or if you wish to return the result of the expression itself

```erl
["My random data", nil] 
|> Enum.random() 
|> (fn item -> if(item, do: item, else: "Sorry... no data!") end).() 
|> IO.inspect
```

or even better

```erl
value
|> something(42)
|> something_else()
|> case do
     page where limit_size == nil -> page
     page -> page |> limit(size)
   end
|> some_more_things()
```

The last example is taken from [elixir forum](https://elixirforum.com/t/how-to-check-for-a-condition-inside-a-pipe-chain/3149/10)

If you wan't your enumerable to go through the pipeline and get an occasional print, if there is a specific key, here is one approach

```erl
[a: 1, b: 3, c: 15]
|> (fn enumerable -> if(a = Access.get(enumerable, :a), do: IO.inspect(a, label: "The :a")); enumerable end ).()
|> (fn enumerable -> if(f = Access.get(enumerable, :f), do: IO.inspect(f, label: "This shouldn't be printed")); enumerable end ).()
|> IO.inspect(label: "The enumerable")
```

Still the best way is to use functions with multiple heads.

Answer (score 0):

Is your response actually a List or a Map? Because Enum.member? won't work on a Map. If it is a Map, you can take advantage of the special pattern matching elixir does for maps to accomplish this in a much easier fashion

```
def show_result(%{"symbol" => _value} = msg) do 
  IO.inspect(msg) 
end 

def show_result(msg) do 
   msg
end
```

Results in this code:

```
msg                                                                                                                                   
|> Poison.decode!                                                                                                                      
|> show_result
```